# Best way to create a copy table in SQL with always updated data from main table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table A. I need to create a copy of A named B. When any insert, update or Delete operation is done on A, the same need to be updated on B. I know it is possible with the help of trigger and i can do that, but does it affect performance. If Bulk insert occur in Table A, will it be inserted to B via trigger without affecting the performance. Or any other way is possible. Any focus in the direction will be helpful.

Comment: Why do you need 2 copies of the same table on the same instance (and database)? This *feels* like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: What is the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: CREATE VIEW B AS SELECT * FROM A would meet the letter of your problem statement as currently written.

Comment: Why do you want two sets of the same data?  Use a view is the best solution here, but like others are asking what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: No one but you knows how to evaluate "best" without a complete understanding of your requirements and resources. Many ways are possible but I agree that this sounds more like a XY problem. You seem to be concerned about performance - do you KNOW if there is a problem or are you prematurely optimizing? But nothing is free - absent a mostly painless approach like a view there will be a cost to keeping that information synchronized.

Comment: Actual scenario is the main table is operated by some other application and it contain years of data and huge number of records, the table B(the copy one) is needed to have copy with some additional columns and markups by a new application. Any change in main table is restricted and the new application need real time data like main table have.

Answer (score 0):

sql-server triggers supporting bulk INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

you can create INSERT trigger on table A like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER A_INSERT
ON A
AFTER  INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO B
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
```

assuming your tables are identical, in terms of columns (and column order),

and you can apply the same principles with delete and update triggers.

**
take in mind it has some affect on performance,
but if B doesn't have any constraints, foreign keys, etc - the performance should not be be affected much

Comment: I would suggest being careful here. If the definition of the `A` or `B` changes while the other doesn't then any any `INSERT`s will fail. If you do go down this route you would be best explicitly defining the columns in both the `INSERT` and `SELECT` clauses.